# My at command failed to reschedule. How can I debug this?

Tags: linux, at

When using `at` is there a limitation on the amount of minutes to use?
E.g I rescheduled programmatically via a script to run in the next 2014.989 minutes (taken from the log) but when I do `atq` I don't see anything listed.
I assume my rescheduling failed? Why? How could I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at does not support decimals:

```
at now + 1.5 minutes
syntax error. Last token seen: .
Garbled time
```

Working version:

```
 at now + 5000 minutes
at> wall "POC"
at> <EOT>
job 8 at Thu Sep 12 23:20:00 2013
```

I guess your best way is to remove what is right of the '.'.
Also at does not seem to accept seconds, from the man page:

> " now + count time-units, where the time-units can be minutes, hours,
>   days,  or  weeks"

As for debugging why your reschedule failed, you should make your script log to a log file: cmd 2&>1 >> /path/to/logfile